# One-To-Many Association without a third table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

OK, so today I tried a basic Hibernate tutorial and I'm struggling to make it behave how I want.

This is a simple snippet, assume all other fields/methods are defined (e.g. id etc.)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CITIES")
public static class City {

    @ManyToOne
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Country country;


}


@Entity
@Table(name = "COUNTRIES")
public static class Country {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<City> cities;
}
```

The above solution utilizes an (automatically created) association table - `COUNTRY_CITIES`, but
this does work only in one way - i.e. I see country's cities (when I select one), but I don't see a city's country (when I select a city).

So what should I do to make cities see their country?

**I can add a `@JoinColumn(name = "COUNTRY_ID")` to the `Country.cities` field and it works in two ways.**

But I don't like to add columns to city's table from country's code.

So I added  the `@JoinColumn` to the `City.country` field and it didn't work.

So - how to make the association work in 2 ways w/o an association table??

---

OK, to be precise: I used the above code add feed the DB with this objects:

```
    Country germany = new Country("Germany", new HashSet<>(asList(
            new City("Berlin"),
            new City("Hamburg")
    )));
```

.. and viewed the DB. It looked like this:

**table COUNTRIES_CITIES** (note, I didn't declare it; Hibernate does automatically)

```
COUNTRIES_ID   CITIES_ID  
1              1
1              2
```

**table COUNTRIES**

```
ID      NAME  
1       Germany
```

**table CITIES** (note I didn't declare the COUNTRY_ID column! Hibernate again..)

```
ID   NAME      COUNTRY_ID  
1    Berlin    null
2    Hamburg   null
```

And that's it. Fetching the country gives me the cities, fetching the city gives me null country.

---

If I add a `@JoinColumn` to the `Country` class, then the a column is appended to the `CITIES` table and fetching works two ways.

Comment: Hey, the class definitions you have provided don't make sense. Are Country and City Inner classes to an outer class? Your class declarations have the static identifier which is illegal in outer class declarations.

Comment: @SpartanElite yeah, they are both nested inside an `public class Example1 { .. }` just to keep it all in one place

Comment: I'm not even going to look at the content of your question, the answers or the comments.  Why would a one to many relationship without a 3rd table *ever* be a problem?  Many to many, sure; one to many -- then you, or somebody else (framework authors?) are doing it wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading your edit problem is clear.

The way you are adding cities and associating with Country...

```
Country germany = new Country("Germany", new HashSet<>(asList(
        new City("Berlin"),
        new City("Hamburg")
)));
```

If you do this then City does not have a country. No where you setting City's country property. ie. `city.country = germany;`
In a **bidirectional relationship** you cannot rely on JPA or your provider to entirely manage  object persistence for you.

So This is what you need to do..

```
Country germany = new Country("Germany");
City berlin = new City("Berlin");
City Hamburg = new City("Hamburg");
berlin.country = germany;
hamburg.country = germany;
germany.cities = new HashSet<>(asList(berlin, hamburg));
germany.saveOrUpdate(); // or whichever definition you use
```

Now in the db you Cities Table will have correct country ids.
Also it is recommended, since this is a bidirectional relationship, that you use the `mappedBy` attribute in your `@OneToMany` relationship. Using it you are telling JPA that cities is the inverse side of the `Country 1-n City` relationship.

Comment: Yes, this was the case. Thank you very much, now I understand the issue. The behavior is not entirely intuitive though :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the `mappedBy` property?

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="country", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<City> cities;
```

For an explanation, look here: [Can someone please explain mappedBy in hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108224/can-someone-please-explain-mappedby-in-hibernate)

Comment: simply adding this only made things worse, now I see neither cities in country nor country in city

Comment: Strange, searching in stackoverflow also suggests this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649032/avoid-relation-table-in-hibernates-mapping-one-to-manyor-one-to-many-associat

Comment: nope, doesn't help... It seems my example works "the opposite" way than expected!

Comment: @Parobay Ben's answer is correct: you need a mappedBy property. If you do not do that, it is very likely you will get other problems later.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that there is a third join table in between? Because then you need to apply the @JoinTable annotation as demonstrated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478328/jpa-jointable-annotation

Comment: He actually does not want a third table. But your link also suggests to use `mappedBy` for his case. @Parobay seems like something else is wrong, its impossible to help you here any further.

Comment: Oh. Oops, I spot it in the title now. Messy problem description threw me off :/ Indeed, mappedBy SHOULD be the solution. So if there is an error, lets see it.

Answer (score 0):

step 1: Add mappedBy at OneToMany side.

```
 @OnetoMany(mappedBy="users")
   private List<Address> address;
```

step 2: Add JoinColumn at ManyToOne Side.

```
 @ManytoOne
 @JoinColumn("userId")
 private User user;
```